# Android ActionBar MenuItem LowerCase

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, lowercase

I want to make MenuItem title in the ActionBar to LowerCase.

my menu.xml

```
  <item android:id="@+id/register"
    android:title="Register"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/unregister"
    android:title="Unregister"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
```

On the ActionBar it sees "REGISTER" and "UNREGISTER", but I want that it sees as "Register" and "Unregister".

Is it possible to make first letter upper and next letters lower at MenuItem?
And how I can do that?

Comment: I've changed my answer. You can check it out

Answer (score 49):

Solution for native ActionBar implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you are using ActionBarSherlock there are two different approaches:

1) Create boolean resource `abs__config_actionMenuItemAllCaps` and set it to `false`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="abs__config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
</resources>
```

2) Or create theme with overriden `actionMenuTextAppearance` and use it in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

<s>**PLEASE NOTE**: there is bug in ActionBarSherlock that forces MenuItem to be upper case on pre-ICS (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/969). I've submitted patch but it is not merged at the moment. For now you can use my fork: https://github.com/alexander-mironov/ActionBarSherlock/tree/dev, I will update this answer when my code is merged in the main repository.</s>

**UPDATE:** my fix has been merged into main ActionBarSherlock repository.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is it possible to set this style programatically to the ActionBar?

Comment: When upgrading to support rev 23.3.0 I had to use textAllCaps without the android package. <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>

Answer (score 26):

Add the following to one of your values xml files -

```
<bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps">false</bool>
```

Answer (score 25):

Just to complete the answer, if you're using AppCompat the parent style is:

```
<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is having no effect for me with AppCompat on an S3 and Nexus 4. I can change other actionMenuTextAppearance attributes such as text size and style. However, the all caps remain. I have rev 21.0.1 of the support library.

Comment: @Mike: It worked with older support libraries. But somehow it does not work in 21.0.x anymore. I wonder why. Maybe they do not want that to work at all? Kind of annoying.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution here? I'm suffering from the same issue.

Comment: When upgrading to support rev 23.3.0 I had to use textAllCaps without the android package. <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>

Comment: yup i'm seeing you need to drop the android package in both places:  <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item> with <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>

Answer (score 18):

For making the menu text to lowercase like "MENU ITEM" to "Menu Item" here is my solution.

In res >> values >> styles.xml add the following:

```
<style name="MenuItemTextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

After you can call it on your AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">...</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried some of the other answers here but to no luck (I'm not using action bar sherlock). As mentioned in the comments, in the newer support libraries, the above solutions don't seem to work. To solve this issue, I added my own actionLayout to the Menu Items.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/yourTitle"/>
```

Then in my code I did something like this.

```
final MenuItem done = menu.findItem(R.id.done);

done.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_kingfisher_text_view);

TextView doneTextView = (TextView) done.getActionView();
```

Then you can do what you want with the text view and avoid the text being all caps. This is definitely not ideal, but if you need a workaround for this issue, this does work.

Answer (score 0):

From source code in android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView

```
//Set text appearance in constructor from style
...
mTextAppearance = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MenuView_android_itemTextAppearance, -1);
...

//Apply text appearance to view item
mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
if (mTextAppearance != -1) {
    mTitleView.setTextAppearance(mTextAppearanceContext, mTextAppearance);
}
```

In project:
Create popup theme and apply it on popup creation for some custom popup if it's planned to use this appearance across whole application then put it to main application theme.

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/FontStyle</item>
</style>

...
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.PopupTheme);
MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(context, menuBuilder, anchorView);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

add theme to toolbar with textAllCaps

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"            
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">          
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```