# "Uncapitalize" tab title in ActionBarSherlock pre-ICS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

So I've been trying to figure out how to uncapitalize the tab titles on ActionBarSherlock. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044790/android-actionbar-menuitem-lowercase) but the second option of the first answer only works with Ice Cream Sandwich+ and I have no idea how to implement the first option (do I just create a XML? Is that all I have to do?).

If it's not possible then that's fine but if it is I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: "do I just create a XML? Is that all I have to do?" -- probably.

Comment: @CommonsWare just tried it and there's no change. Is there any way I have to include it in another part of the project? 

I've never really used resources or styles before so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: The instructions basically ask you to create a `res/values/bools.xml` file (where boolean resources go by default) with the cited XML. Now, it's entirely possible that the answer has bugs -- I find action bar tabs to be worse than useless and so I have never tried what the answer calls for.