# Lowercase option menu text in toolbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, optionmenu

Shortly, I want to make option menu text in lower case, for example, `save`, not `SAVE`. 
My app use toolbar in the latest appcompact library. I tried many ways but don't work at all.
There are some related questions but don't work for me:
[Android ActionBar MenuItem LowerCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044790/android-actionbar-menuitem-lowercase)  
[How to change ActionBar Tab textStyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250105/how-to-change-actionbar-tab-textstyle)
What I tried:

```
<style name="MyIDAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main</item>

    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Really annoyed that Google doesn't provide an option for developers to custom as they want. 
 Is there any suggestion?

Comment: There is a opened issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172591&thanks=172591&ts=1431349509) into android issue tracker

Answer (score 2):

try it custom menu

Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem saveMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_save);
    if(saveMenu != null){
        LinearLayout saveLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_save_menu_layout, null);
        saveMenu.setActionView(saveLayout);
        saveMenu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

custom_save_menu_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: After doing this, the onClickListener should be added manually, otherwise the menu item onClick is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Put it on your app theme:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> 
    </style>
```