# Android Toolbar MenuItem LowerCase

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar

I want to make MenuItem title with lower case in the Toolbar.
my menu.xml

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Done"/>
```

On the Toolbar it shows as "DONE"  but I want that it show it as "Done". I tried to solve this case by Using textAllCaps="false" but I could not find any proper parent class to apply style for "actionMenuTextAppearance".

What would be the right solution, I need a guidance here, Thank you.

Comment: Show your styles.xml code.

Comment: <style name="menu_textOnlyStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>


this is my style and I used it in my AppTheme as :

 <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/menu_textOnlyStyle</item>

Comment: @SantoshBhandary has the answer right here for creating a style and putting it in the app's theme. This is the only solution I've found that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_done"/>
```

**instead of this**

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Done"/>
```

**and in strings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="action_done">Done</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: Thank you but I already tried the way you told,it does not work .

Comment: have you tried like `<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">`

Comment: and you can refer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044790/android-actionbar-menuitem-lowercase for  more detail

Comment: And the style i have mentioned?

Comment: yes ,you can see the style I have tried in the comment  in Question .