# Appcompat 22.2 shows menu in capital case rather than lowercase

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using the following style to change the menu to lower case but it does not work.
I've searched on the internet for references but I couldn't find anything.I think there is problem with the library.If anyone has an answer please tell me.

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044790/android-actionbar-menuitem-lowercase

Comment: I already gone through above answer but its does not work for me

Comment: try to add <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>  in your AppBaseTheme theme below api level 21 and <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> in api level 21 and above.

Comment: Tried this allso but not working<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        -->
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

Comment: Vote for the bug report... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185548